# Is it possible to get Modifier IDs returned in /items endpoint?

Tags: square-connect

I understand from the docs that the /items endpoint does not return the price modifiers for an item, and that you must call the /item endpoint to get them. I'm assuming this is because there is a lot redundant data that would be returned otherwise. I have over 400 items and am trying to avoid calling /item 400 times just to get the associated Modifiers. Is there any way to at least get the item's modifier ID(s) returned from the /items call? If so, I could then just call the /modifier-lists endpoint to get all Modifiers and then match them up to the items by the Modifier ID.
Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is not currently a way to do what you're looking for with the items endpoint. However, if you're willing to accept some added complexity you can query for item details 30 at a time using the [batch endpoint](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/index.html#navsection-batching) and save yourself some round trips. Keep in mind that you can also dispatch multiple HTTP requests in parallel once you have the item IDs.

Comment: Thanks Troy. I am actually batching the requests, 30 at a time. I'm currently not dispatching multiple requests for fear of hitting the rate limit.

Comment: I think you can get away with some amount of parallelism. My suggestion would be to try it and pull back if you start getting 429s.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [List Catalog endpoint](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-listcatalog) to retrieve a list of all of your item modifiers.